# How can an if code block continue from where while loop left off in such cases?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I don't have any experience with coding at all and I have just started learning Python.

In John Guttag's book "Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python With Application to Understanding Data", at the beginning of chapter 3, there is a code example:

```
#Find the cube root of a perfect cube
x = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
ans = 0
while ans**3 < abs(x):
    ans = ans + 1
if ans**3 != abs(x):
    print(x, 'is not a perfect cube')
else:
    if x < 0:
        ans = -ans
    print('Cube root of ' + str(x) + ' is ' + str(ans))
```

What I have a hard time understanding is how "if" outside of "while" can pick up from where the loop left off with the iteration? If it is because of the last iteration of ans which gets it out of the loop and also satisfies the if condition, how does the if condition work for the values of ans and thus x inside the loop?(ans^3 is not equal to x only inside the while loop, how come can this part work:

```
 if ans**3 != abs(x):
     print(x, 'is not a perfect cube')
```

I really don't know how else to ask this but this is the code that I came up with before I peeked at the code in the book, it worked, and maybe it wil help to clarify what I am exactly asking:

```
x=int(input('Enter an integer: '))
crx=0

while True:
    if crx**3<abs(x):
        crx=crx+1
    elif crx**3==x:
        print('The cube root of',x,'is',str(crx)+'.')
        break
    elif crx**3==-x:
        print('The cube root of',x,'is',str(-crx)+'.')
        break
    else:
        print(x,'is not a perfect cube.')
        break
```

In my mind, somehow, I had to insert the if code blocks inside the while loop...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It doesn't. The while loop runs to completion, it modifies the variable `ans` and then the `if` statement checks the value of `ans` that resulted from running the while loop.

Comment: The while loop runs until the `ans**3 < abs(x)` condition is no longer met. In the process of the loop the `ans` variable gets modified, in this case adding one to the variable.

Comment: You can verify by adding `print(ans)` inside the loop and then outside the loop, before `if`

Comment: @Metropolis: Thank you, but, if that is so, how come can it print what is not a perfect cube? The resulting `ans` is the one whose cubic power is equal to x anyway?

Comment: So, consider this: x = 4 (not a perfect cube). The loop begins. 0\**3 is less than 4, so we add 1 to ans. 1\**3 is less than 4 so we add 1 to ans. 2\**3 is not less than 4, so **the loop ends** and ans is now equal to 2. Then we check: if ans\**3 is equal to 4. Since ans is 2, ans\**4 is 8. So it isn't equal to 4. So it prints "4 is not a perfect cube". Notice the loop runs to completion. Then the if statement runs later. It doesn't enter to loop. It just uses the value of ans that the loop created.

Comment: @Metropolis: Think I got it upon reading it again. Thank you. I realize the the premisconception I had was that once it checked in the while loop that 2**3 is not 4, as you said in your example, it dumped 2 from its memory. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure thing. This is why I suggested adding those print(ans) statements to your code and running it. It will show you how the value changes at each step. It can help with understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a consequence of `if` going back to the `while` loop. Let's examine the control flow:

x is being set as an integer from string `input`

`ans` is initialized with value `0`, an `int`

```
x = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
ans = 0
```

To check if something has a cube root, the while loop takes every integer greater than `0` and cubes it, if the cube is *less* than `x`, then we increase `ans` by `1`, otherwise, `ans` is saved and the `while` loop exits. Note, the otherwise covers if the cube is greater than *or equal to* `x`.

```
while ans**3 < abs(x):
    ans = ans + 1
```

If the resulting `ans` is equal to `x`, then `x` has a cube root. If it is not, then `x` is not a cube root.

```
if ans**3 != abs(x):
    print(x, 'is not a perfect cube')
else:
    if x < 0:
        ans = -ans
    print('Cube root of ' + str(x) + ' is ' + str(ans))
```

Comment: Sorry for not realizing that it stored the iteration whose cube exceeded x and because of that, it gave the "it's not a perfect cube result". I couldn't pick up on it for the first time, plus, Thank you. Removed my earlier comment because it included yet another needless question.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms - the loop makes sure the value of `ans` is the lowest (non-negative) integer whose cube is greater than or equal to `x`. Note the following consequence:

- if `x` is a perfect cube, then the final value of `ans` will be exactly that cube root (because we know that `ans**3` must be equal to `x`.
- If x is not a perfect cube, then the final value of `ans` must be such that `ans**3` is strictly greater than `x`. In particular, it will not be equal to it.

So the calculation is purely done in the `while` loop - and after this, the `if` checks if you calculated an exact cube root, or whether you don't (in which case this was never possible, because `x` was not a perfect cube). And of course it prints an appropriate message to the user in either case.

(I just saw the edit with your own solution - yes, as you observed, that also works fine. There is rarely only one way to solve a problem with code.)